# How to modify the default port of docker swarm?

Tags: docker-swarm

If I want to use docker swarm in my system, I know I must open port 2377,7946 and 4789. And I know that the port 2377 and 4789 can be changed through --listen-addr and --data-path-port, but I didn't find any option to change port 7946. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick research to see if it was released yet. But by the looks of some GitHub issues for instance [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39280), it does not look like they made any progress on the topic itself. By the look of the [swarm init](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/) and [swarm update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_update/) it does not look there would be any sign of the documentation stating there could be any config to do such a thing.

Comment: By the looks of the already open question [Is it possible to customise the swarm port? How to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151496/is-it-possible-to-customize-swarm-port-if-so-how-to-do-this) it does not look like any good news as well.